# How to reverse the value of column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe with one columm "Name" and two rows.

```
Input: Name
       ABCD
       XYZ

Output: Name
        DCBA
        ZYX
```

I have searched online and the solution is to reverse the row/column order. Kindly suggest how can I reverse the value in a column in A DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a loop. Assuming strings, you could use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

or a list comprehension:

```
df['Name'] = [x[::-1] for x in df['Name']]
```

Output:

```
   Name
0  DCBA
1   ZYX
```

If you don't have only strings, a safer approach would be to check for the type:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1] if isinstance(x, str) else x)
# or
df['Name'] = [x[::-1] if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in df['Name']]
```